# Breeze - removing element from cache

Tags: breeze

I am keeping local entities in breeze cache, how can i delete them from the cache with out going to the server?
in the documentation it states

> Deleting an entity
>   You delete an entity by changing its EntityState to “Deleted” like this:

1
someEntity.entityAspect.setDeleted(); // mark for deletion
setDeleted does not destroy the object locally nor does it remove the entity from the database. The entity simply remains in cache in its new “Deleted” state … as changed and added entities do. A successful save does delete the entity from the database and remove it from cache.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by detaching the entity from entity manager by calling manager's detachEntity method :

```
manager.detachEntity(entity);
```

The detached entity will eventually be garbage collected.

Refer to [Breeze-Inside Entity](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/inside-entity)

Comment: Are there any guidelines for undoing changes for each component/screen? Facing an issue where one Angular component does `.createEntity()`, but then the user goes to a differen component (without a page refresh, so the `createEntity()` is still being tracked). Is it advised to just put `rejectChanges()` at the start-up and destroy of each component, to avoid pending changes from a previous long-gone component?

Answer (score 0):

You can do 
    entity.setDeleted();
and then call 
    saveChanges method.
if you want to save it in DB.
if not want to go to server 
manager.detachEntity(nameofYourEntity);